# Error: http://localhost:8081/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LuuDzNw net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: angular, typescript-typings

i am getting this error while connecting to socket.io. can anyone suggest me what will be the issue? i am using node js and typescript.

`GET http://localhost:8081/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LuuDzNw 
    net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: have you tried using the host ip instead of localhost?